# Using variables inside other classes without static in java

Tags: java, class

So I'm basically supposed to use variables from my objects created from the Employee class below:

```
public class Employee {

     public long EmployeeNumber;
     public String EmployeeName;
     public String LastName;
     public double HoursWorked;
     public double HourlyWage;

    public Employee(long EmployeeNumber, String EmployeeName, String LastName, double HoursWorked, double HourlyWage ){

        this.EmployeeNumber = EmployeeNumber;
        this.EmployeeName = EmployeeName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.HoursWorked = HoursWorked;
        this.HourlyWage = HourlyWage;
    }


    public double getAnnualGrossSalary(){ // calculates annual gross salary
        return HoursWorked*HourlyWage*52;
    }
```

There are Employee objects created from my main class, multiple Employee objects stored inside of an arrayList.

Now what I'm trying to do is use these variables from these Employee objects inside of another class to calculate taxes.

```
public double calculateTax() {

    if (Employee.getAnnualGrossSalary() < 41495){
        return Employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.16;
    }
    else if (Employee.getAnnualGrossSalary() < 82985){
        return Employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.20;
    }
    else if(Employee.getAnnualGrossSalary() < 100970){
        return Employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.24;
    }
    else
        return Employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.2575;

}
```

I have a method written out for this in another class but when I try to use them, it keeps saying:

`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAnnualGrossSalary() from the type Employee`.

How do I fix this?

Just to clarify, if I make it static, nothing else works in my program so there's absolutely no way I can make it static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Employee` is the class type, it is not an object instance. If the method `getAnnualGrossSalary` was static then you could use `Employee`.

You should try to pass an instance of the `Employee` class into the method:

```
public double calculateTax(Employee employee) {

    if (employee.getAnnualGrossSalary() < 41495){
        return employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.16;
    }
    else if (employee.getAnnualGrossSalary() < 82985){
        return employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.20;
    }
    else if(employee.getAnnualGrossSalary() < 100970){
        return employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.24;
    }
    else
       return employee.getAnnualGrossSalary()*0.2575;
}
```